# VPN ERROR 500 STATE_MAIN_I1, unable to start phase2

Tags: ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, openswan, fortigate

i'm trying to set up a site to site vpn to a fortigate 60c from a CentOS 7 with openswan, the error i get everytime is the following

```
000 #1: "office":500 STATE_MAIN_I1 (sent MI1, expecting MR1);
EVENT_v1_RETRANSMIT in 8s; nodpd; idle; import:admin initiate
000 #1: pending Phase 2 for "office" replacing #0
```

my configuration files

office.conf

```
conn office
left=%defaultroute              # Your local linux machine IP
leftsubnet=192.168.3.0/24       # The subnet of your local Linux machine
leftid=@openswan               # Same as given in Sonicwall
leftnexthop=%defaultroute
#    leftxauthclient=yes
right=mrt.mx          # Sonicwall VPN IP
rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24     # Sonicwall LAN subnet
rightid=office          # Sonicwall Unique Identifier
#    rightxauthserver=yes
#    keyingtries=0
#    pfs=yes
auto=start
auth=esp
esp=3DES-SHA1                 
ike=3DES-SHA1
ikelifetime=1800s
authby=secret
aggrmode=no
#    leftmodecfgclient=yes

dpddelay=30
dpdtimeout=60
```

ipsec.conf

```
  GNU nano 2.3.1                              Fichero: /etc/ipsec.conf                                                                      

version 2.0     # conforms to second version of ipsec.conf specification
# basic configuration
config setup
# Debug-logging controls:  "none" for (almost) none, "all" for lots.
# klipsdebug=none
# plutodebug="control parsing"
# For Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Fedora, leave protostack=netkey
protostack=netkey
nat_traversal=yes
interfaces=%defaultroute
oe=off
# Enable this if you see "failed to find any available worker"
nhelpers=0
include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
```

Comment: Have you enabled dead peer Detection on both sides? Review each setting to make sure they match on both sides exactly.

Comment: yes, also disabled aggresive mode on both

Comment: Have you tried the opposite?  Enabling aggressive mode?  Can you append the foreigner config?

Comment: my bad i actually solved this but i haven't posted the answer

Comment: @JulioVillalba would you mind posting the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following error, which I read on a post that it won't matter, but I did had to enable forwarding, it solved this error and allowed to establish connection
Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding            [FAILED]

```
 `sysctl -w net.ipv4.forwarding=1`
```